# Multiple parameters in slacks slash command with Zapier

Tags: slack-api, zapier

I have a slash command in slack calling into a zapier webhook.

The sample command I've setup is:

> /todo [Title] [User]

In Zapier, there is an attribute called **text** in the incoming webhook that maps **[Title] [User]** as a string value. The problem is that I want to be able to get access to individual variables and not just a text string representing the entire command.

Is there a way in Slack to split variables such that I can map [Title] to a Title form attribute in the POST command and likewise the [User] to a User attribute?

If not, is it possible to do string parsing / string index in Zapier?

Comment: How did you get slack to take those variables? http://stackoverflow.com/q/34234180/843443

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading an article on Zapier for [Named Variables](https://zapier.com/help/named-variables/), I figured that I had to modify the command format in slack to the following:

> /todo title(Item title) assigned(User Name)

Then, Zapier started to show variable names Title and Assigned in the action field.

Comment: I had to do something similar. I think the problem is the "system" doesn't know when the Title ends and when the User begins. So you need some kind of delimiters. In my case I was able to do `/cmd "user" other stuff`