# How to get variables from slack custom command into param

Tags: node.js, slack

I wrote a node app that takes a `d` param and responds with a random dice roll:

```
https://{some app}.herokuapp.com/roll/dice?d=20
```

The user can also add a number to the end of the dice roll like:

```
https://{some app}.herokuapp.com/roll/dice?d=20&a=5
```

The api works fine. I am trying to get this to integrate with slack so that users can type

```
 /roll 20
```

or

```
 /roll 20 5
```

but I am unable to figure out how to get variables into the params. How do I pass those variables into the custom command? Here is a screenshot of what I got set up so far:

[image: slack error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out the only way. You have to POST data instead of GET, and parse the 'text' parameter.

Comment: i am facing same issue, but azure function is not able to recognize values, Please explain how to do it in C#.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/send-http-post-request-in-net